# Kernel Debugging: Gdb not able to set breakpoints and no effect of SIGINT to bring back in Debugging Session

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

> > Linux Kernel : 4.13-rc7 x86_64

Configured Buildroot and Qemu for Linux Kernel Debugging.

Launch Qemu using following Command:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-4.13-rc7/arch/x86/boot/bzImage   -initrd buildroot-2017.02.5/output/images/rootfs.cpio  -append "root=/dev/ram0 console=tty0 kgdboc=ttyS0,9600 kgdbwait"  -chardev pty,id=pty -device isa-serial,chardev=pty`

Now, In Next terminal window, launch gdb and proceed following gdb commands:

`

```
gdb-peda$ file vmlinux
Reading symbols from vmlinux...done.
warning: File "/root/drive/linux-4.13-rc7/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /root/drive/linux-4.13-rc7/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
gdb-peda$ target remote /dev/pts/3
Remote debugging using /dev/pts/3
Warning: not running or target is remote
0xffffffffbd6f65af in ?? ()
gdb-peda$ b start_kernel
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff81f79ad7: file init/main.c, line 510.
gdb-peda$ c
Continuing.
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff81f79ad7

Command aborted.
gdb-peda$ `
```

**I also tried in Qemu machine:**

`echo "g" > /proc/sysrq-trigger`. But, nothing happened .

Also, tried to set Hardware Breakpoints using `hbreak` on `start_kernel`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution by own , I did the following things to get working solution:

> - Apply patch to gdb then recompile it with patch in `<$GDB_FOLDER>/gdb/remote.c` file.

**GDB Patch to resize its internal buffer :**
`

```
root# diff -u gdb-8\ \(1\).0/gdb/remote.c gdb-8.0/gdb/remote.c

--- "gdb-8 (1).0/gdb/remote.c"  2017-06-04 21:24:54.000000000 +0530
+++ gdb-8.0/gdb/remote.c    2017-09-05 23:27:46.487820345 +0530
@@ -7583,7 +7583,27 @@

   /* Further sanity checks, with knowledge of the architecture.  */
   if (buf_len > 2 * rsa->sizeof_g_packet)
-    error (_("Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: %s"), rs->buf);
+    //error (_("Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: %s"), rs->buf); #patching
+    {
+      warning (_("Assuming long-mode change. [Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: %s]"), rs->buf);
+      rsa->sizeof_g_packet = buf_len ;
+
+      for (i = 0; i < gdbarch_num_regs (gdbarch); i++)
+        {
+          if (rsa->regs[i].pnum == -1)
+            continue;
+
+          if (rsa->regs[i].offset >= rsa->sizeof_g_packet)
+            rsa->regs[i].in_g_packet = 0;
+          else
+            rsa->regs[i].in_g_packet = 1;
+        }
+
+      // HACKFIX: Make sure at least the lower half of EIP is set correctly, so the proper
+      // breakpoint is recognized (and triggered).
+      rsa->regs[8].offset = 16*8;
+    }
+ 

   /* Save the size of the packet sent to us by the target.  It is used
      as a heuristic when determining the max size of packets that the`
```

> - Build the minimal RootFS by Buildroot.
> - Launch Qemu by following command and launch new gdb then load vmlinux file .
> - In one terminal :
>
>   `root# qemu-system-x86_64  -kernel /root/drive/linux-4.13-rc7/arch/x86/boot/bzImage  -initrd /root/drive/buildroot-2017.02.5/output/images/rootfs.cpio  -S -s`
> - In another terminal :
>
>   `gdb -q /root/drive/linux-4.13-rc7/vmlinux -ex "target remote localhost:1234"`
>
> Now set break point at `start_kernel` and continue, It will automatically hit the breakpoint.